Boundary conditions in $\delta I=0$ to derive Einstein's equations -- why the derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$ are held constant?
Dirac derives Einstein's field equations from the action principle $\delta I=0$ where $$I=\int R\sqrt{-g} \, d^4x$$ ($R$ is the Ricci scalar). Using partial integration, he shows that $$I=\int L\sqrt{-g} \, d^4x$$ where $L$ involves only $g_{\mu\nu}$ and its first derivatives, unlike $R$. Clearly $L\sqrt{-g}$ is both the action density in four dimensions as well as the Lagrangian density in three dimensions, since $$I=\int L\sqrt{-g} \, d^4x = \int dt \int L\sqrt{-g} \, d^3x.$$ Dirac considers the $g_{\mu\nu}$ to be the 'coordinates', and their time derivatives $g_{\mu\nu,0}$ the 'velocities', so by the action principle he determines the actual 'path' $g_{\mu\nu}$ which turns out to be Einstein's field equations (in the same way that the Euler-Lagrange equations determine the equation of motion).
When performing the variation $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ he assumes $g_{\mu\nu}$ is constant on the boundary of the four-dimensional volume $D$ in the action integral
$$I=\int_D R\sqrt{-g}d^4x.$$ This parallels the classical variation method where $I=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} L ( q^i, {\dot{q}}^i ) \, dt$, and one assumes $q^i(t_0)=q^i(t_1)$ for all paths, i.e., all paths are constant at the endpoints (the 'boundary').
However, Dirac also assumes that we keep "the $g_{\mu\nu}$ and their first derivatives constant on the boundary." This is essential in two separate places where the divergence theorem is used, because there are Christoffel symbol terms that contain derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$.
How does one explain the need to assume that both $g_{\mu\nu}$ and their first derivatives are constant on the boundary (other than the fact that it's required for the action principle method to work)? Transitioning from the usual 'principle of stationary action' in 1D to the same principle in 4D, is it clear how the spatial derivatives of the 'coordinates' $g_{\mu\nu}$ come into play?
References:

Dirac, “General Theory of Relativity”, Ch 26, pp 48-50.


You don't assume it. The GHY boundary term precisely cancels terms that depend on the normal derivative of the metric on the boundary. We only assume that the metric is fixed on the boundary. Also - please provide references.

More on boundary terms in GR.

@Prahar Dirac assumes the derivatives of the metric are constant on the boundary, and this is indeed necessary in his derivation of the EFE.

@KhunChang - Yeah, he probably did not know about the GHY boundary term. I implore you to learn from more modern resources (Dirac was an absolute genius, but learning from a dated textbook makes no sense).

I am using multiple sources but Dirac’s book is extremely concise and yet very readable and accessible. Some of his derivations are unique and the mathematics is often gorgeous. (I am a retired mathematician.) It seems worthwhile to go through his 69-page treatise as a starting point to other more expansive books. For the most part Dirac is flawless but on this issue I think he skipped a beat and cheated slightly. See my comments below to Alves.

@Prahar Another thought: the principle of stationary action assumes a finite region for the integral, but the resulting Euler-Lagrange equations are local. Therefore, the original domain of integration is arbitrary. If we let the boundary go to infinity, then in practical, physical terms, spacetime is flat far away from all matter and energy, so the metric is Minkowski and the derivatives are zero — satisfying the hypothesis of the variation. Is this a valid argument?

@KhunChang - The boundary terms must include ALL boundaries of spacetime. In particular, if you go along null directions in asymptotically flat spacetimes, you reach null infinity ${\cal I}$. Spacetime NEVER becomes flat along this limit because you always have gravitational waves. Your argument can apply to spacelike infinity (since nothing ever reaches this boundary) but doesn't apply to null or timelike infinity.

I was thinking 3D. Thanks!

The Einstein–Hilbert action is incomplete. It involves a boundary term with contains second derivatives of the metric, but which does not affect the resulting Einstein equations (if you derive them using the Euler–Lagrange equations for higher order Lagrangians). Dirac is just solving this issue in a handwaving manner. The correct approach is to add the Gibbons–Hawking–York term to the Einstein–Hilbert action, which gets rid of the second derivatives in the Lagrangian and makes the assumption of constancy of the derivatives of the metric unnecessary. This is done, for example, in Poisson's A Relativist's Toolkit.
Let me be a bit more clear about Dirac's approach. If you do not remove the boundary term with the GHY term, you end up with a higher-order Lagrangian, in the sense that the Lagrangian depends on the field, on its derivatives, and on its second derivatives. To make a simple toy model, let us consider the action
$$S = \int L(\ddot{q},\dot{q},q,t) \,\mathrm{d}t.$$
If one holds $q$ and $\dot{q}$ fixed at the boundary, one gets that $\delta S = 0$ leads to the modified Euler–Lagrange equations
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot{q}}\right) - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0.$$
Typically this equation will be of fourth order in $q$, and hence one does need four boundary conditions (two for $q$ and two for $\dot{q}$). Therefore, the correct approach is indeed to hold $q$ and $\dot{q}$ fixed at the boundary.
However, the particular case of the Einstein–Hilbert action has a second-order dependence only by means of a boundary term. In this particular case, it turns out that the equations of motion for the higher-order Lagrangian are the same as for the regular Lagrangian that ignores the boundary term. This is why Dirac manages to derive the Einstein equations: they are indeed the Euler–Lagrange equations for the Einstein–Hilbert action, but in a higher-order sense. However, he is forced to use the higher-order formalism, and thus has to keep the derivatives fixed at the boundary. A better approach is, of course, to employ the Gibbons–Hawking–York term to get rid of the second-order terms and getting a well-defined variational problem in the standard sense.
If you're interested in learning more about higher-order Lagrangians, I recommend a 2020 paper by Ganz and Noui, available at arXiv: 2007.01063 [hep-th].

Thank you! I think I’ve found a detailed discussion of this in Padmanabhan, Ch. 6 starting on page 239.
Appears Dirac just glossed over a significant issue.

So you are saying that Dirac should have either (a) used a “better” Lagrangian that has only first derivatives and produces the Einstein equations by fixing only the metric on the boundary; or (b) used a Lagrangian with first and second derivatives and kept the metric and its derivatives fixed on the boundary, and shown how the Einstein equations still result.
Instead, he followed (a) but also specified keeping the first derivatives of the metric constant on the boundary — which in principle could overspecify the problem.

@KhunChang From your brief account, I think he followed (b), since he started with the Einstein–Hilbert Lagrangian. He would need to start with a different Lagrangian to follow (a)

Not exactly. He started with the E-H action, but changed the Lagrangian to a different one that has only 1st derivatives of the metric. Then he churned out Einstein's equations BUT he assumed that $g_{\mu\nu}$ and its derivatives are constant on the boundary. He cheated a bit here. He could have stuck with the E-H action with its 2nd derivatives, kept his boundary conditions, and then (more work?) derived Einstein's equations. OR he could have changed to a Lagrangian (more work) that yields Einstein's equations with ONLY the boundary condition that $g_{\mu\nu}$ is constant on the boundary.

@KhunChang If he used that the derivatives of the metric are fixed after changing the Lagrangian, then I believe he took a wrong route. If he made this assumption in order to change the Lagrangians, then he followed route (b).

I see what you mean. I will reread it carefully tomorrow. Many thanks - very helpful comments.

Well the news isn’t good. He uses the constancy of the derivatives on the boundary twice: the second time after he changed to a Lagrangian that involves only first derivatives of the field (but yielding the same action). I think he’s cheated. I suppose if he stuck with the original EH action he would have gotten a 4th-degree Euler-Lagrange eqn that must be degenerate in some way and reduced to Einstein’s equations. OR he should change the Lagrangian to the York-Hawking as others have said.

Another thought: the principle of stationary action assumes a finite region for the integral, but the resulting Euler-Lagrange equations are local. Therefore, the original domain of integration is arbitrary. If we let the boundary go to infinity, then in practical, physical terms, spacetime is flat far away from all matter and energy, so the metric is Minkowski and the derivatives are zero — satisfying the hypothesis of the variation. Is this a valid argument?

@KhunChang It is impossible to get a fourth-order equation from the EH action, because the higher-order terms are boundary terms

@KhunChang spacetime does not need to be flat away from matter and energy: black holes and gravitational waves are vacuum solutions. Also, I never saw any rigorous text doing calculus of variations outside a compact set. I believe the problem might not be well-defined if you ignore boundaries.

Thank you. Surprisingly, Weinberg’s text just says we integrate over all space and ignore the boundary terms. I’m going to work carefully through the GHY Lagrangian to settle the issue.

@KhunChang Weinberg's text is definitely not rigorous
